# Why is this creating TWO windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class GameWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        self.minsize(width=GAME_WIDTH, height=GAME_HEIGHT)
        self.maxsize(width=GAME_WIDTH, height=GAME_HEIGHT)
        self.title('Hangman!')
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Initial Hangman Background
        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"D:\Python\Projects\Hangman\Images\StartScreen.png").subsample(2, 2)
        self.background_label = tk.Label(image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.image = self.background_image
        self.background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1, y=0)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Easy", command=lambda: print("Easy"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Intermediate", command=lambda: print("Intermediate"))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Hard", command=lambda: print("Hard"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()
```

Comment: `def __init__(self): tk.Tk.__init__(self)`

Comment: The code you posted absolutely will _not_ create two windows.